# Where can I ask questions about developing for/on/with Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am developing some gadgets for Stack Exchange (a userscript, an application that uses SE API, etc.). I have some questions specific to utilizing SE's resources (API, web page DOM, etc.) during development. What's the proper place to ask?

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackapps.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is the right place to ask questions about the Stack Exchange API and other resources.

You can also use that site to publish your apps and scripts that are directly relevant to SE, and in some cases you may need to make a placeholder post there to be able to use certain resources.